# Text is getting hidden in chart js while testing on phone

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

[Error image is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgPn4.png)

I am develooping chart in my application which is working working fine in web browser but while i am testing the changes as UAT testing on phone then on galaxy S5 phone its hiding the text.

Please let me know if you require anything else from my side as the i am getting stuck here.

```
function dashboardPieChart() {
    Highcharts.chart('dashboardPieChart', {
        colors: [
            '#cff484',
            '#4c89d3',
            '#8bbc21',
            '#910000',
            '#1aadce',
            '#492970',
            '#f28f43',
            '#77a1e5',
            '#c42525',
            '#a6c96a'
        ],

        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'

        },
        title: {
            text: 'Wallet Balance'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: false,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name} RM {point.y:.2f}</b>',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || '#4c651e'
                    }


                }

            }
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: 'Balance',
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: [
                    {
                        name: 'Balance',
                        y: Number($scope.currentBalance.replace(',', '')),
                        sliced: true,
                        selected: true

                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Market Cap',
                        y: 10000 - Number($scope.currentBalance.replace(',', '')),
                        sliced: true,
                        selected: true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

And the code from the HTML Page is like b

```
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div id="dashboardPieChart">
                      <!--   style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because the width of your screen is too small to display correctly the 2 texts.

So you can add the option: `textOverflow: 'none'` in `plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.style`.

So your plotOptions become:

```
        plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: false,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name} RM {point.y:.2f}</b>',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || '#4c651e',
                    textOverflow: 'none'
                }


            }

        }
    },
```

This is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/noswx17b/1/